Performing PLU decomposition for two distinct matrices with the same orthogonal P
Say I have two distinct invertible matrices, $M_1$ and $M_2$.
We know that there are two orthogonal matrices, say $O_1$ and $O_2$, such that $O_1M_1$ and $O_2M_2$ have an LU decomposition:
$$
O_1M_1 = L_1U_1, \quad O_2M_2 = L_2U_2.
$$
My question is: can we guarantee the existence of a matrix $O_3$ such that both $O_3M_1$ and $O_3M_2$ have LU decompositions? i.e.
$$
O_3M_1 = L_1'U_1', \quad O_3M_2 = L_2'U_2'
$$
In other words, is there always an orthogonal matrix that simultaneously "cleans up" the singular leading principal minors of two distinct matrices? Intuitively, this seems likely: any invertible matrix can be infinitesimally perturbed so that it remains invertible and has an LU decomposition (if I remember correctly). Still, I haven't been able to come up with a proof.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.
